# What does "ele" mean and the rule of this code in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, brightness

The code is for adjusting the contrast and brightness of any image, I have no idea what does `cimg[i, j] = [int(ele) if ele < 255 else 255 for ele in lst]` mean ? especially `[int(ele) if ele < 255 else 255 for ele in lst]`, I haven't seen these code rule before, please help me, Thank you guys !

Another question, Does "ele" means every element in the array ?

```py
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            lst = 0.1*cnum*img[i, j] + bnum
            cimg[i, j] = [int(ele) if ele < 255 else 255 for ele in lst]
```

Comment: That is a list comprehension. See for example here: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you ! I will check it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, the code contains **List Comprehension**. Which is a simple and clean way of creating a new list from an iterable.

This code can be rewritten without using list comprehension.

```
for i in range(img.shape[0]):
    for j in range(img.shape[1]):
        lst = 0.1 * cnum * img[i, j] + bnum
        pixel = list()
        for ele in lst:
           if ele < 255:
              pixel.append(int(ele))
           else:
              pixel.append(255)
        cimg[i, j] = pixel
```

[This is a nice tutorial to understand list comprehension](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-list-comprehension?utm_source=adwords_ppc&utm_campaignid=1455363063&utm_adgroupid=65083631748&utm_device=c&utm_keyword=&utm_matchtype=b&utm_network=g&utm_adpostion=1t1&utm_creative=332602034364&utm_targetid=aud-299261629574:dsa-486527602543&utm_loc_interest_ms=&utm_loc_physical_ms=9062041&gclid=Cj0KCQjw6cHoBRDdARIsADiTTzac-hpxLazxNyJXPt9pKQNL6-tG7gof2V2qFUB_L0AE68yOIATRuVUaArV7EALw_wcB)